I'm having trouble assigning custom colors to map polygons based on specific value ranges in Oracle Apex
Color List:
My custom colors are defined as:
['#D1D1FF', '#0EAD00', '#00FF00', '#FFFF00', '#FE7F00', '#DE0000']
Data Table Structure:
My data is stored in a table with the following relevant columns:
From: Defines the start of each range.
To: Defines the end of each range.
Category: An alphabetical value ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), assigned to each range.
Color: Specifies a color based on the category.
Additionally, there’s a Value column that stores the value for each polygon.
Value Ranges:
My data is divided into these ranges (inclusive-exclusive):
0-1, 1-4, 4-7, 7-10, 10-100.
Problem:
When I tried setting the Color Value Column based directly on the Value column, the colors appeared randomly (or fine but not within the specific range).
I then tried setting colors based on the From column:
This partially worked: the colors for ranges 0-1 and 1-4 displayed correctly.
However, the color for the 4-7 range was skipped (yellow) and the color for the 7-10 range (orange) was applied instead, followed by red for 10-100.
How can I correctly apply the colors to the polygons so that each value range displays its corresponding color from the custom list?
